# How to generate smooth vertex weights from edge/face selection?

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I am rigging a character for animation and am sick of manually "painting" the vertex weight corrections because I always get bad results. Is there a way to auto-generate weights based on a selected edge loop or face loop?

[image]

I have a problem transfering the vertex weights to the shirt, so now I have to touch it up again, and it is very difficult to do with the brush. Notice how the hem of the shirt doesn't have nearly enough weight (if any) applied to it (note: this goes for the ends of the sleeves and the collar too). I have to paint these weights in by hand, but if I do, it's going to look splotchy and I will not get a clean result.

What I would like to do, is just select all those faces and say "based on this face loop, generate new vertex weights with Smooth Falloff and an intensity of 1.00 (or whatever). Can this be done?

Answer (score -1):

This could be it: Gradient fill. Blender's best-kept secret.

https://youtu.be/bQBlMTt8SrU